# Combining Multiple Event Methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

Looking to refactor some application code. I have a GUI that has several of the same events that are reflected for different labels, textboxes, etc...

For example:

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
    }
```

and

```
    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
    }
```

I just assign these methods to the event on the object properties in Visual Studio. Is there an efficient way to combine multiple event methods to clean up the code? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

Define a single event like:

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
        textBox.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
}
```

and then assign that event to all your TextBox Enter event like:

```
textBox1.Enter += textBox_Enter; //Same event handler
textBox2.Enter += textBox_Enter; //Same event handler
```

Answer (score 0):

If both event handlers do the same exact logic, as you probably have listed here, just create 1 event handler and assign it to both components.

```
private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null) {
        textBox.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate slightly you can take this approach even when you want to perform different actions depending on the control that fired the event.

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the sender is textBox1
    if(ReferenceEquals(sender, textBox1))
    {
        //Perform action on textBox1
    }

    //Check if the sender is textBox2
    if(ReferenceEquals(sender, textBox2))
    {
        //Perform action on textBox2
    }
}
```